# How to create the jspf file in intelliJ IDEA

Tags: java, intellij-idea

When I want to create a jspf file in a java web project,that only JSF and JSP options,no JSPF
How can I do for it. 
Thanks

Comment: The question's not clear, plz see [ask].

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no predefined file template for .jspf files. But you can [create](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/creating-and-editing-file-templates.html) your own:
[image]

and use it from the 'New' action popup menu:

[image]